# How to work with babel in cucumber js project?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, babeljs, cucumberjs, babel-polyfill

I have a cucumber js `4.2.1` and I want to use babel before running the tests.

I couldn't find any documentation/tutorial about this integration.

Does anyone know how to do that?

- Bonus: Using the latest babel versions (7.0.0 (not beta)).

---

To be more specific, currently, when running cucumberjs from the command line, I don't specify the feature files folder and the steps folder:`./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js.cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using protractor with cucumber you can use babel-register:

See an example here: https://github.com/canvaspixels/cucumber-protractor/blob/master/sample-conf.js

Just add:
`require('babel-register');` to the top of your conf and install the babel-core npm package.

I highly recommend using cuketractor to structure your project and reduce boilerplate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vuYL4nxMXs

Comment: what is my `conf` file? I'm not using Protractor. I'm using testCafe.

Comment: Ah my bad on that assumption. Yeh the conf is for protractor

Comment: Please write in the title of your answer that this is an answer for anyone who uses `cucumber` with `protractor`. I bet it will help a lot of developers.

Comment: Done, nice one!